# paramiko exec_command "sudo -iu" hangs

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko (newbie) to connect to a linux server. I'm able to connect to the server an execute different commands (such as 'ls', 'uptime') and to read the results.
However, when trying to execute the 'sudo -iu' command (doesn't require a password), the Paramiko hangs. Here is the relevant code lines:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy (paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sh.connect (server, username='aaaa', password= 'bbbbb', key_filename='C:\\Users\\aaaa\\Documents\\paramiko_dsa_key')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo -iu aaauser")
        #stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("uptime")
        print stdout.read()
```

Note, that there are no issues running these commands using known SSH tools such as Xshell.

Thanks in advance,
Tal

Answer (score 6):

Paramiko hanging is exactly what would be expected. When you do `sudo -i`, a new shell is spawned and the current shell goes into I/O wait until the newly spawned shell exits, at which time control would be turned back to Paramiko.

Running `sudo -i` would thus never result in output to stdout, and so your loop would be stuck in I/O wait, and thus hang, as you are currently experiencing. `sudo -i` should never be used in scripts, it should only be used for interactive shells.

You have two options:

1. Configure the SSH daemon to allow logins as the user `aaauser` and avoid this problem in the first place.
2. Execute each command using `sudo` in the normal, non-interactive fashion.